How to read from a varytpe 8209 variable?
I am using VBscript inside a third party software. My ways of seeing what is going on is by writing to a log file or using MsgBox.
When trying to read some data about a polygon object, the variable's vartype is 8209 which as I believe is an array bytes, aka vbByte.
The data inside this variable called GEOMETRY should be some form of the below:

I have tried:

for each x in GEOMETRY
Which results in an error of "Type mismatch"

v = GEOMETRY(0)
Which results in an error of "Type mismatch"

Ubound(GEOMETRY)
Returns 1179


I am currently trying to see if there is some way of feeding GEOMETRY into a ADODB.Stream, but I don't have any code for that that I think even should work yet.
Edit: Also, I do know GEOMETRY IS A 1D ARRAY SINCE UBound(GEOMETRY,2) fails
Edit2:
I was able to load it into an ADODB.STREAM obj but results aren't great.
Using
Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.STREAM")
BinaryStream.Type = 1 'binary
BinaryStream.Open
BinaryStream.Write GEOMETRY
MsgBox("Size " & BinaryStream.Size & vbNewLine & _ 
    "vartype " & vartype(BinaryStream.Read))

Results in a size of 1180 with a vartype of 1, aka vbNull.

It might be a 2D Array, try GEOMETRY(0, 0) to get the first value -229138.479164.

@user692942 I knew I was forgetting to add something. It is a 1d array as far as I can tell since UBound(GEOMETRY,2) fails as does GEOMETRY(0,0).
Post edited to that would be clear going forward, thank you.

VBScript does not support the byte data type.
Save the ADODB file to disk and read it in as a ANSI text file. Then scan the string using 'asc() to get the byte value. Your computer/program should use US locale.

And how does one save it to disk? I have tried to .Write my GEOMETRY variable but it fails with because it is invalid. Presumably because it is an array, not a string.

stream.writetofile
